# Count no of column having null and non null value

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have query in which i want to sum of null(0,'', NULL) and non null values in a single row.

Example: I have a table having 5 column. It contain atleast one record. In its first row 2 columns are blank and 3 columns are having some value. I want a query which will give me a result like non_null_count=3, null_count=2

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: Do you want that for each row or overall? And Zeroes and empty strings are not the same as NULL.

Comment: @dnoeth i want it for each row. because whole thing is in a loop. and i am getting each row one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Count of `NOT NULL` data-

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  salary IS NOT NULL 
       AND emp_name IS NOT NULL 
       AND manager_id IS NOT NULL
```

Count of `NULL` data-

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   employee 
WHERE  salary IS NULL 
       AND emp_name IS NULL 
       AND manager_id IS NULL
```

Comment: You can use subquey @irshad khan

Comment: `SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE salary IS NOT NULL AND Emp_name IS NOT NULL AND Manager_Id IS NOT NULL)  as Not_Null_count,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE salary IS NULL  AND Emp_name IS NULL  AND Manager_Id IS  NULL) as NUll_count  FROM employee`

Comment: This counts either rows were *all* columns are NULL or *all* columns are not NULL, but not mixed NULL/NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT ( IF(col1 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) 
         + IF(col2 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) 
         + IF(col3 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) +... ) AS total_not_null, 
       ( IF(col1 IS NULL, 1, 0) 
         + IF(col2 IS NULL, 1, 0) 
         + IF(col3 IS NULL, 1, 0) +... )     AS total_null 
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: thanks @Vu nguyen it is working fine for null values only. how to do this for "blank" and 0 also in same query

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, boolean expressions can be treated as numbers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.

So, this does what you want:

```
select ((col1 is not null) + (col2 is not null) + (col3 is not null) +
        (col4 is not null) + (col5 is not null)
       ) as num_not_null,
       ((col1 is null) + (col2 is null) + (col3 is null) +
        (col4 is null) + (col5 is null)
       ) as num_null
from t;
```

Note that this interprets "blank" as being `NULL`.  You can just as easily use `<> ''` or similar logic if "blank" means something else.

EDIT:

For other values, you need to extend the logic.  A simple way is:

```
select ((col1 is not null and col1 not in ('0', '')) +
        (col2 is not null and col2 not in ('0', '')) +
        (col3 is not null and col3 not in ('0', '')) +
        (col4 is not null and col4 not in ('0', '')) +
        (col5 is not null and col5 not in ('0', '')) 
       ) as num_not_null,
       ((col1 is null or col1 in ('0', '')) + 
        (col2 is null or col2 in ('0', '')) + 
        (col3 is null or col3 in ('0', '')) + 
        (col4 is null or col4 in ('0', '')) + 
        (col5 is null or col5 in ('0', '')) 
       ) as num_null
from t;
```

Comment: thanks @Gordon Linoff it is working fine for null values only. how to do this for "blank" and 0 also in same query